# Чому ми називаємо неробочі дні "вихідними"?

Tags: етимологія

**Чому ми називаємо неробочі дні "вихідними"?**

У мене є лише одна теорія: хтось колись кудись виходив. Є кілька російськомовних ресурсів (наприклад, [Вікісловник](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)), які намагаються зрозуміти етимологію російського *выходной*, проте вcі вони розходяться в поясненнях.

А ще цікаво, коли саме так почали називати вільні від роботи дні (тижні, загалом, будь-які часові проміжки).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Вихідний* — [запозичене](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) з російської мови іноземне слово. Тож варто звернутись до [російської](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18378/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) етимології.

> Слово **вихідний** (і день, і людина) застосовувалось спочатку до
>   працівників, які обслуговували дім господаря і **працювали не виходячи з хазяйського двору**. Їм давали інші дні для виходу дні, не
>   пов'язані з загальними неробочими днями. Тож 
>   сам працівник називався *«вихідним»*.

Тільки згодом вихідними стали називати загальні неробочі дні.

Answer (score -2):

Від німецької Wohenende вохененде - кінець тижня. В українській мові дуже багато запозичених німецьких слів.

Comment: Welcome to Ukrainian Language! We usually prefer longer and more elaborated answers. If you can improve your post by adding detail, context, and examples, this would increase your answer's quality to help other users. Low quality answers are risking being down-voted and subsequently removed. Please take your time to [edit] and elaborate your post. In any doubt, please make sure you've taken a look at [tour], [answer], and [our guide](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/) to quality answers.

Comment: Цікава версія. Однак, здається, історики й етимологи її не підтримують. (Я зараз не про мінуси конкретно на цьому сайті, а про те, що ніде в джерелах її знайти.) Чи, може, Ви здаєте щось, що може її підтвердити?

Comment: «Лінгвістика — це така наука, де приголосні не означають нічого, а голосні означають ще менше». © Певно, автор вважає, що запозичення виду *Wohenende → вихідний*, з усіма оцими трансформаціями `wо → ви`, `he → хі`. зниклою `N`, `eNDe → ДНий` — то так і має бути. :)